# Extracting position of pattern in a string using ifelse in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a set of strings `x` for example:

```
[1] "0000000000000000000000000000000000000Y"   "9000000000D00000000000000000000Y"        
[3] "0000000000000D00000000000000000000X"      "000000000000000000D00000000000000000000Y"
[5] "000000000000000000D00000000000000000000Y" "000000000000000000D00000000000000000000Y"
[6]"000000000000000000000000D0000000011011D1X"
```

I want to extract the last position of a particular character like 1. I am running this code:

```
ifelse(grepl("1",x),rev(gregexpr("1",x)[[1]])[1],50)
```

But this is returning -1 for all elements.  How do I correct this?

[image]

Comment: adjust my code according to what?

Answer (score 0):

In base R, the following returns the position of the last matched `"1"`.

```
# Make some toy data
toydata <- c("001", "007", "00101111Y", "000AAAYY")

# Find last postion
last_pos <- sapply(gregexpr("1", toydata), function(m) m[length(m)])
print(last_pos)
#[1]  3 -1  8 -1
```

It returns `-1` whenever the pattern is not matched.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stri_locate_last` from `stringi`.  If there are no matches, it will return `NA`.

```
library(stringi)
r1 <- stri_locate_last(v1, fixed=1)[,1]
r1
#[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA 40
nchar(v1)
#[1] 38 32 35 40 40 40 41
```

If we need to replace the NA values with number of characters

```
ifelse(is.na(r1), nchar(v1), r1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <-  c("0000000000000000000000000000000000000Y", 
      "9000000000D00000000000000000000Y", 
      "0000000000000D00000000000000000000X",
      "000000000000000000D00000000000000000000Y",
      "000000000000000000D00000000000000000000Y", 
      "000000000000000000D00000000000000000000Y", 
      "000000000000000000000000D0000000011011D1X")
```

Comment: Can I use ifelse with stri_locate_last to have it return an element every row?

Comment: if along with 1 I want to check for multiple elements like 1,2,3 simultaneously?